# Java varargs constructor gives error in subclass constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, variadic-functions, superclass

I have 2 classes: `FinishButton` and `ChangeSpeedButton`.
`FinishButton` is the parent class, but it is from a different package and it is a subclass of another class.
It has 2 constructors:

```
public class FinishButton extends Button {

    public FinishButton(Point...points) {
        super(Response.SLOW,Type.HOLD,points);
    }
    public FinishButton() {
        this(new Point(width-75,height-75),
                new Point(width-75,height-15),
                new Point(width-15,height-15),
                new Point(width-15,height-75));
    }

    public void function() {
        nextPanel();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        super.draw(g);
        this.xpoints[0] = 0;
        g.setColor(Defaults.GRAPHIC_COLOR);
        int[] xPoints = { 
                width-45-(int)((20*Math.sqrt(3))/2),
                width-45-(int)((20*Math.sqrt(3))/2),
                width-45+(int)((20*Math.sqrt(3))/2)
        },
                yPoints = {
                height-65,height-25,height-45
        };
        int nPoints = 3;
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    }

}
```

These classes are works in progress but `ChangeSpeedButton` looks like this:

```
public class ChangeSpeedButton extends FinishButton {

    public ChangeSpeedButton() {
        super(new Point(width/2-30,height-75),
                new Point(width/2-30,height-15),
                new Point(width/2+30,height-15),
                new Point(width/2+30,height-75));
    }

}
```

The weird thing is that `FinishButton` handles the varargs perfectly when overloading its own constructor, but for some reason on `ChangeSpeedButton`'s constructor, **Eclipse** is telling me to

> either "remove arguments to match 'FinishButton()'" or "Change
>   constructor 'FinishButton()': Add parameters
>   'Point,Point,Point,Point'".

Does anyone know why it's giving me an error on `ChangeSpeedButton`?

Edit: I added the full classes. And as requested, here is the `Point` class:

```
public class Point {

    private double x,y;

    public double getX() { return x; }
    public double getY() { return y; }

    public Point() {
        this(0,0);
    }
    public Point(double x,double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Point: ("+x+", "+y+")";
    }

}
```

Maybe it has to do with the fact that the Button classes are nested classes?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, though I don't know where `width` and `height` comes from, or what their type is, or even what type `Point` is.

Comment: can't reproduce.. may be post the classes (including `Point`) with declaration and all the constructors and width/height variable declarations and we may find some typo

Comment: width and height come from the class that the button classes are nested in

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness. I'm so dumb. I had 2 FinishButton files open and even though I saved one of them with the correct changes, the ChangeSpeedButton only looked at the outdated file.

Comment: Use the auto-save feature.